# How to make keyboard work like OSX System Wide?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I switch frequently between elementary OS and OSX, and it is really hard dealing with shortcuts like: cut, copy, paste, new, new tab, close window, close all.

So, basically I am asking the exact same question with this ubuntu thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/10008/how-to-make-keyboard-work-like-osx-system-wide
(I even kept the same title.)

Is there a way to do it using:
Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Custom ?

I have also tried using `autokey-gtk` with no luck, after adapting [this](https://github.com/metakermit/dotfiles/tree/master/autokey) repository folder from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/319896/34777) answer.

## Note:

Swapping command with control it is not a solution.